# CASE com IN não funciona

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Estou querendo fazer essa busca abaixo:

```
DECLARE @codccu VARCHAR(10);

SET @CodCcu = '63'
  SELECT E.codepi, 
             E.numcad, 
             Max(E.datent)            AS ENTREGA, 
             Max(E.datent) + P.diaval AS VALIDADE, 
             CASE 
               WHEN Max(E.datent) + P.diaval <= Getdate() THEN 'VENCIDO' 
               ELSE 'OK' 
             END              AS SITUACAO 
      FROM   r096die E, 
             r096epi P 
      WHERE  E.numcad = 241 
             AND 
                CASE  
                    WHEN @codccu IN ('911003','63') THEN E.codepi IN (1,6,23,24) 
                    ELSE E.codepi IN (1,23)
                END                         
             AND P.codepi = E.codepi 
      GROUP  BY E.codepi, 
                E.numcad, 
                P.diaval
```

Sendo que, quero buscar os `codEpi` `(1,6,23,24)` se o centro de custo for `('911003','63')` , se não quero que liste os códigos com os números `(1,23)`

Mas apresenta o seguinte erro:

> *Sintaxe incorreta próxima à palavra-chave 'IN'.. Error 156. SQLSTATE 42000. Severity 15. MsgState 1. Line 18.*

Que se trata dessa linha:

```
WHEN @codccu IN ('911003','63') THEN E.codepi IN (1,6,23,24)
```

Eu já pesquisei e não consigo encontrar onde estou errando nesse script, já tentei também da seguinte forma:

```
AND E.codepi =
                CASE  
                    WHEN @codccu IN ('911003','63') THEN IN (1,6,23,24) 
                    ELSE  IN (1,23)
                END
```

mas apresenta o mesmo erro.

Comment: Se você substituir `IN (1,6,23,24) ` por `1,6,23,24` funciona! Na verdade você não pode ter vários resultados na mesma linha. O resultado é um pra cada linha!

Comment: Agradeço ajuda @Marconi, mas desse modo não funciona, pelo motivo da virgula ele vai ser perder não sabendo qual deve buscar.

Comment: Esqueci de colocar aspas!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não pode utilizar um `IN` no resultado de um `CASE`. Substitua por uma estrutura com `OR`:

```
WHERE  E.numcad = 241 
  AND ((@codccu IN ('911003','63') AND E.codepi IN (1,6,23,24))
   OR (E.codepi IN (1,23)))        
  AND P.codepi = E.codepi
```